# DJANGO: caching a services.py method so it's always available

Tags: django, caching

I'm trying to use this python ML library and turn it into an APIView for my project. There is a single line that loads the ML model which took around ~20s, so I separated that line into services.py and decorated with @lru_cache so it doesn't always take ~20s.

Because lru_cache is Least Recently Used caching method, the cached model is quickly un-cached and makes user wait for another 20s sooner or later.

So I am looking for a way to either cache `load_model()` method so it's always available, or cache it within a certain time. I tried using cache_page method for the latter but had no luck so far.

Is there a better method I can use, or would just tweaking the lru_cache's maxSize be a more elegant solution? This APIView isn't called very often, which makes user wait ~20s every time. I was hoping to just make it always available so user don't have to wait.

#### views.py

```
from .services import load_model, extract_keyword

class ExtractKeyphrase(ApiAuthMixin, APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            text = request.data["text"]
            kp_model = load_model()  # the line that takes ~20s
            keyphrases = extract_keyword(kp_model, text)

            return JsonResponse(keyphrases, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            Response("Request Failed", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#### services.py

```
from functools import lru_cache
from keyphrasetransformer import KeyPhraseTransformer
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

# @method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 60 * 24))
@lru_cache(maxsize=2)
def load_model():
    kp_model = KeyPhraseTransformer()

    return kp_model
```

Answer (score 0):

If `kp_model` does not change, you don't have to use cache, just a global variable:

```
# in another module, e.g kp_model.py
_kp_model = None

def get_kp_model():
    global _kp_model
    if not _kp_model:
        _kp_model = KeyPhraseTransformer()
    return _kp_model
```

You can load it on first POST API request:

```
class ExtractKeyphrase(ApiAuthMixin, APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            text = request.data["text"]
            keyphrases = extract_keyword(get_kp_model(), text)

            return JsonResponse(keyphrases, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            Response("Request Failed", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Or you can load it at django startup by adding:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        get_kp_model()
```